# Problem with using c++ in VsCode (error printed in the terminal after running the code)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, windows-10

After running my code, the terminal printed that g++ is not recognized as an internal and external problem, I don't know how to proceed with the setup.

Comment: That means `g++` is not in one of the folders of your system `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: We'll, step 0 is *always post any error messages you are asking about as text in the question, verbatim*. We are not mind readers and we cannot see your screen. An interpreted (usually faulty) explanation of an error message is not helpful. Just post the raw error, *always*. Don't ever try to interpret and explain what you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a C/C++ compiler? You might need to install one if you don't but otherwise you might have a problem with your build file.